# Default Initialization of Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am translating a C++ program into JavaScript.

In C++, when a dynamic array of type float/double is created, its entries are initialized to 0.0 by default; I don't have to explicitly initialize the entries.

So a 1-D vector of size 3 looks like (0.0 0.0 0.0)T, where T indicates the transpose of the vector.

A 3 x 3 matrix is initialized to

```
[0.0 0.0 0.0;
0.0 0.0 0.0;
0.0 0.0 0.0]
```

It saves me a few lines of code, and speeds up the program (by not repeating what has been done already.)

Does JavaScript offer comparable functionality?
If not, I will initialize explicitly:

**E.G,
Code:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) v[i] = 0.0;
```

Otherwise, can somebody here suggest the fastest way to initialize 1-D and 2-D arrays to 0.0?

Comment: read up on `undefined`.

Comment: Note that if you use a typed array, it’s initialized to zeroes; try `new Float32Array(9)` in your console, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ES6, you could use [`Array#fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill).

```
var array = Array(3).fill(0);
//                ^           size of the array
//                        ^   value of element
```

ES5

```
var array = Array.apply(null, { length: 3 }).map(function () { return 0; });
//                                      ^                                    length
//                                                                    ^      value
```

Comment: To the OP. If you are after speed avoid the use of apply and map. They are extremely slow, and in this case uses double the memory (apply creates an array, that is then used just to provide an iterator to create a second array via map). A simple for loop is much quicker `var array=[];for(var i=0;i <3;i++) array[i]=0;` and does not have to create a new stack context for each item in the array for any callback functions like map does.